# Proving strong convexity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to prove that $f$ is strongly convex, where
$$f(x)=\|Ax-b\|_2^2$$
$A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \ b\in \mathbb{R}^m$. I found the gradient, which is 
$$\nabla f(x)=2(A^TAx-A^Tb).$$
Any ideas on how to prove strong convexity? What properties must $A$ satisfy for $f$ to be strongly convex?

Answer (score 2):

Compute
$$
(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y))^T(x - y) = \\
2(A^TA(x - y))^T(x - y) = \\
2(x-y)^TA^TA(x - y)
$$
Take $s$ to be the *smallest* singular value of $A$.  Then we have
$$
2(x-y)^TA^TA(x - y) = 2\|A(x-y)\|^2\geq 2s^2\|x - y\|^2
$$
and in fact, this is the lowest coefficient we can get on the right so that the above holds.  So, $f$ will be strongly convex if and only if all singular values of $A$ are non-zero, which is to say that $A$ has full column-rank.

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to be a square matrix. How exactly are we going to find the singular values?

Comment: The singular values come from the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.  $A^TA$ is necessarily a square matrix.

Comment: Singular values can't be negative.  $A^TA$ is automatically positive semidefinite

Comment: @LinAlg full **column-rank**, as I said.  If $A$ is a wide matrix, then $s = 0$ even if $A$ has "full rank".